# How to do a JOIN without duplicates that don't match the condition?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to join `tags.url = urls.url` but the problem is in my query I'm getting tags that don't have the same url in `urls` table.

This fixes it adding a WHERE clause that makes sure the url is the same in both..but I'm not convinced this is the proper way to do a JOIN in SQL:

`SELECT urls.*, tags.tag FROM urls LEFT JOIN tags ON urls.url = tags.url WHERE tags.tag = ? AND tags.url = urls.url ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 50`

I'm using sqlite.

If I leave off the `AND tags.url = urls.url` then I get tags that match the tag where clause but urls isn't a match on the join.

Comment: If you want only the matching rows of the tables then you should do an INNER join.

Answer (score 0):

From [sqlite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#fromclause)

> If the join-operator is a "LEFT JOIN" or "LEFT OUTER JOIN", then after the ON or USING filtering clauses have been applied, an extra row is added to the output for each row in the original left-hand input dataset that corresponds to no rows at all in the composite dataset (if any). The added rows contain NULL values in the columns that would normally contain values copied from the right-hand input dataset.

All the `tags` rows are returned. A simple JOIN will find the "intersection" of the two tables.

Comment: please provide code

Comment: drop the word "LEFT"  (and the AND clause) from the posted sql.